# Laravel Backpack 4.0 Documentation for Pivot and PivotFields within CRUD Controller

Tags: laravel-backpack

I'm using a select2_multiple field within Backpack for Laravel and the relationship that I'm working with has additional pivot table values.

Within the documentation it references

`'pivot' => true, // on create&update, do you need to add/delete pivot table entries?`

This is all the information that is provided. While troubleshooting I've come across other documentation / posts that are referring to `pivotFields`.

Can someone please shed light on what this flag is actually doing and if there are additional requirements that are not documented correctly.

Comment: Hmm... let me rephrase this so I know we're talking about the same thing. So you're looking for a field that will not only SELECT the related entry, but also allow the admin to input extra info, that you'd store on the pivot table? If so, I'm afraid we don't have anything like that right now. But you _could_ add individual text fields for the extra data on the pivot table, and do the storing/updating in the setupCreateOperation() and setupUpdateOperation() methods...

Comment: Also - just remembered that there's a PR proposing a solution for this - https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/pull/351

Comment: I’m not asking for any features. Just documentation on this functionality.

Comment: Oh, I get the confusion now. That feature is not complete yet - that's why it has no documentation. There are proposed changes to it, like the PR I mentioned above, so I'm not really sure you can use it as-is. Unfortunately I didn't do this in any of my projects, so I'll let someone else who has done this help out. Feels like I'd do more harm than good trying to direct you how to use it. Sorry I can't be of any help.